# "Like you" or "As you", works as an answer in the following context?

Tags: phrase-usage

If my girlfriend and I are in a restaurant and she told me that she wants 3 cutlets and then she asks me "And you?" or "How many do you want?", can I tell her "**Like you**." or "**As you**." meaning that I want 3 too?

Alternatives - for example - that I can think of are:

- The same as you.
- I want 3 too.
- I also want 3 cutlets.

But I'm not asking about the alternatives but about these two specific examples that I asked about.

Answer (score 1):

"Like you" is clear but informal. "As you" isn't very clear, but we might say "the same as you".

A more typical way to answer the question is, "I'll have the same. "

Comment: Really? "Like you" makes no sense to my ears in this context. "The same as you" is the natural response that I would hear.